# Microsoft Azure Storage - Success Percentage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I added a microsoft azure storage to my hosting strategy and moved about 15gb if videos to Azure. I set up the CDN endpoint and it seems fine and i have no complaints . But I added monotoring and cant understand the "Success percentage" indicator and why would it not be 100%?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because some requests can go wrong:

- Throttling
- Authentication failed (SAS key expired for example)
- Client / Server Timeout
- Network errors

The complete list of possible errors can be found here: [Storage Analytics Logged Operations and Status Messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh343260.aspx)

Comment: A am new to azure and the default dashboard paints Availability (BLOB), Success Percentage (Blob) and Total Requests (Blob). Success Percentage (Blob) is at 33.15%  This is very worrysome but site seems to work fine. All these blobs are FLV video assets and i am hopeful its a false indication of browser realizing video is cached verses 66% failure to get video. It doesn't seem like i can drill in deeper using the azure web dashboard ... is that correct? I would now need to locate code/write some code to use the statistic tables being collected on Azure to know more?

Answer (score 0):

Sandrino was mostly correct however a page which may have a postback has a http 304 on assets which are chached. Currently azure reports that in its fail to deliver percentage. I belive thsi is going to be changed next console update.